# difference between importing a component vs importing react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Hello every one i just want to know the mechanism behind how importing react from 'react' works in my cra-app but for my component i have to import it by defining the path of the component file in a nutshell why is there a difference between thee two statements

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because React is using Webpack internally to resolve modules. In the first import `import React, { Component } from 'react';` webpack will look for the library in the `node_modules` folder as it has a `resolver` configured to do so.

In the second case you need to mention the path or alias the path `./Button` with a shorter name like '`button'` to tell Webpack where to search/resolve in that directory inside the `webpack.config.js`.

For an app created using create-react-app, the `webpack.config.js` will be located in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`.

There you would notice this resolver is defined which tells Webpack where to look for the core libs:

```
resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
        // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
        process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
      ),
     ...
}
```

To alias your own path you can define a new alias in that file located in the `config/webpack.config.js` after you eject the app with `npm run eject` (you cannot undo this):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components' : path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/Components')
    }
  }
};
```

In you component you can import like:

```
import Button from 'components/Button';
```

Answer (score 1):

`react` is a package installed via `npm` into `node_mudules` and can be imported by the package name.

`Button` is your custom component, and thus has to be imported by its path. If you made `Button` into a package, then you could install it via npm as well.